# Will it be possible to run C code emulated on GA144?

Tags: c++, c, forth, emulation

This company have [an interesting CPU](http://www.greenarrays.com/home/products/index.html) that run at an amazing speed. Will it be possible to emulate C or is the memory too small?

Comment: Hah,  Chuck Moore is still kicking!  He's not going to like your idea.

Comment: [A C translator](http://www.asu.ru/files/documents/00002991.pdf) is available for the SEAforth40 chip. Just download, change the file extension to .zip and unpack. The user-guide is here: [C Translator User Guide](http://www.asu.ru/files/documents/00002989.pdf). If you need help, ask :)

Comment: How did I get here and think any of this is a good idea?

Answer (score 5):

There is C translator for SEAforth40 chip (previous version of GA144 chip)

Presentation:
http://www.asu.ru/files/documents/00002990.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A first cursory glance at the instruction set suggests that "colorForth" can be thought of as a simple machine language. Given that, it may be possible to write a C compiler that compiles to colorForth as its target instruction set.

Of course, it may be easier to write code in colorForth in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, if someone writes a compiler which can output the machine code (33 instructions, not too complex), you won't need to emulate C, you could just directly compile it.

Of course, it would be extremely limited, since it looks like each chip gets a tiny amount of internal RAM (64 words isn't a lot to work with). There's an 18-bit memory address port attached to one of the cores, so you can have 256MB of external RAM, but it can only be directly accessed by a single one of the cores, and then it would need to be passed to the other.

It's possible that different cores could be used for different functions, but that would complicate the compiler quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done, but their interpreter should handle parallel tasks, load distribution, etc. It will probability be best to just go with their Forth interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Chlorophyll has some ideas of general interest. I also happens to look similar to C:

> We developed Chlorophyll, a synthesis-aided programming model and
>   compiler for the GreenArrays GA144, an extremely minimalist
>   low-power spatial architecture that requires partitioning the program
>   into fragments of no more than 256 instructions and 64 words of
>   data. This processor is 100-times more energy efficient than its
>   competitors, but currently can only be programmed using a low-level
>   stack-based language. The Chlorophyll programming model allows
>   programmers to provide human insight by specifying partial
>   partitioning of data and computation. The Chlorophyll compiler relies
>   on synthesis, sidestepping the need to develop classical
>   optimizations, which may be challenging given the unusual
>   architecture. To scale synthesis to real problems, we decompose the
>   compilation into smaller synthesis subproblems—partitioning, layout,
>   and code generation. We show that the synthesized programs are no more
>   than 65% slower than highly optimized expert-written programs and are
>   faster than programs produced by a heuristic, non-synthesizing version
>   of our compiler.

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~mangpo/www/talks/1311_forthday_handout.pdf

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~nishant/papers/Chlorophyll.pdf

Comment: These URLs are dead. Took a bit to track down the updated links: http://pl.eecs.berkeley.edu/projects/chlorophyll/ and https://github.com/mangpo/chlorophyll

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use external memory, but apart from that, it is certainly doable, according to this [white paper](http://greenarrays.com/home/documents/greg/WP002-100405-energycons.pdf) by [Greg Bailey](http://greenarrays.com/home/about/bios.html):

> It would not be difficult to build a virtual  machine supporting C,
>   and there are  many people and companies in the US  alone for whom
>   building such a machine  and completing a “port” of the C  language
>   compiler and library to the  virtual machine would be simply a 
>   repetition of something they had done  before. Once this has been
>   done, the  GreenArray chip can run any C program  which fits in the
>   external memory and  will satisfy any C application  requirement that
>   is met by the resulting  execution speed.
>
> -- excerpt from page 4

He also discuss their implementation of a eForth virtual machine in that paper.